# Jenkinsfile parallel loop - parallel getting only the last value of array

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am making a jenkisfile which create parallel jobs. It looks something like:

```
def list = ['a','b','c']
node('ser'){
  stage{
    for item in list{
      jobs[item] =
      { 
        ws("${item}"){
          bat "powershell echo item: ${item}"
        }
      }
    }
  parallel jobs
  }
}
```

The problem is that it prints:

```
"item: c"
"item: c"
"item: c"
```

and not:

```
"item: a"
"item: b"
"item: c"
```

It seems like because `jobs` is outside of the for, `parallel jobs` only get the value of the last iteration.

I think that if I only give the value of the item, and not a `${item}` it would work. But how can I do it?

Or maybe other solution?

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer -

**"GROOVY GOTCHA: FOR LOOPS AND CLOSURE SCOPE":**

http://blog.freeside.co/2013/03/29/groovy-gotcha-for-loops-and-closure-scope/

Comment: Please add relevant notes from the page you linked to his answer.

Comment: This link is not working for me. I'm having the same issue and I can't access the answer